# How to use Docverter from Httpie?

Tags: pandoc, httpie, docverter

I'm trying to render adocument using [docverter](http://www.docverter.com/) from [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie). All the examples are for Curl. I tried

```
http -f POST http://c.docverter.com/convert from=markdown to=html input_files@example.txt --output out.html
```

But the website throws an error

> TypeError at /convert
>   can't convert Symbol into Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it pretty close. Your `http` invocation should look like this:

```
http --form -f POST http://c.docverter.com/convert from=markdown to=html input_files[]@example.md --output out.html && open out.html
```

While debugging I found a bad typo and shipped v1.0.1 and installed it on the public instance.